# Make link wrap to avoid overflowing into other elements

Tags: html, css

I want to format this so that the link wraps to a second line and the delete stays vertically centered in the well, rather than the delete dropping down to get out of the way, as it is in the fiddle below. Nothing I have tried so far has worked, but I'm admittedly pretty poor with CSS.

Code:

```
<div id="listing_10" class="well">
       <a href="#">Words words words words words words words words words words words</a>
       <span class="pull-right">
           <a style="text-decoration: none" class="delete_listing" href="#">
               <i class="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle danger"></i><strong class="danger" style="vertical-align: middle"> Delete</strong>
           </a>
       </span>
</div>
```

Here's the jFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ohbnkok8/4/

Note:

The text of the link will be at most 50 characters.

Comment: Under what conditions should it wrap? It's a single word, where would you have it wrap? In the fiddle (and in your code too) delete is not centered in `well`, how can it *stay* centered? Do you mean vertically centered?

Comment: The markup is invalid, so you should expect confusion.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I mean vertically centered. I want it to wrap when it would collide with the <span> containing the delete link. And @JukkaK.Korpela, how is the markup invalid?

Comment: To make it a bit more sensible, just put your delete `<span>` above your words `<a>`. It won't be centered (vertical centering is kind of hard), but I actually prefer to have it top-aligned, as a user. Give `<span>` a bit of `margin: 0 0 5px 10px;` for more prettiness. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohbnkok8/5/)

Comment: @rfj001, it was invalid in the first version where you had `li` without enclosing `ul` or `ol`.

Comment: @Amadan the link will only be at max 50 characters, so it will only be 2 or maybe 3 lines at small screen sizes. I feel with this small amount of text center-align looks best. Is it really that difficult to implement?

Comment: With `float`, difficult. With a `table` (or elements with `display: table-cell`), easy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [this???](http://jsfiddle.net/chakrei/ohbnkok8/6/)

Add few CSS

```
a {display: inline-block; max-width: 80px; vertical-align: middle;}
```

Comment: Notice in the fiddle how when you change the size of the screen the delete button moves up and down? I would like it to remain vertically centered.

Comment: The reason for that is you have added pull-right class. Now, it becomes a floating element. Try changing its position to fixed but even then if the screen becomes too smaller you will notice the change of button's position.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the bootstrap grid system to make things work. The delete button isn't centered, but it is always even with the top line, which for the typical 1 line case that I'll be seeing will make it centered, and still looks nice when there are 2 or 3 lines.

```
<div id="listing_10" class="well">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-7'>
            <a href="#">Words words words words words words words words words words words</a>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 text-right'>
            <a style="text-decoration: none" class="delete_listing" href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle danger"></i><strong class="danger" style="vertical-align: middle"> Delete</strong></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ohbnkok8/12/